# Have Single repository to persist entity depending on the name of the entity

Tags: spring-data-jpa

My Question is that I have 7-8 entities and each will be having same code.Without writing individual for each of the entity how can i write the code in Spring Data for all the entity in one repository depending on that the entity/model name which is to be persist

```
public interface LoginRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity1,Integer>{
}

public interface LoginRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity2,Integer>{
}
public interface LoginRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity3,Integer>{
}

public interface LoginRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity4,Integer>{
}
```

Any way of doing it

Comment: Anyone have any solution to this